# Angular 2 Template Driven Form access ngForm in component

Tags: angular

I want to use template driven forms in Angular 2 and I need to access the current ngForm in my directive, as local property and I don't want to pass them as parameter.

my form looks like this:

```html
<form #frm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(frm)">
    <input [(ngModel)]="user.name" #name="ngForm" type="text">
    <a (click)="showFrm()" class="btn btn-default">Show Frm</a>
</form>
```

and in my component

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'addUser',
    templateUrl: `Templates/AddUser`,
})

export class AddUserComponent implements CanDeactivate {
    public user: User;
    // how can I use this without defining the whole form 
    // in my component I only want to use ngModel
    public frm : ngForm | ControlGroup;

    public showFrm()  : void{
        //logs undefined on the console
        console.log(this.frm);
    }
}
```

Is this possible, because I need to check if the myFrm ist valide or was touched in a function where I can't pass the current form as parameter e.g. "routerCanDeactivate" and I don't want to use model driven forms its way too much to write in code and I love the old school ng1 model binding.

I've updated my Example and the frm is not known in the component.

Comment: I've created a  feature request on github: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8538

Comment: Should the `AddUserComponent` be placed within the form as a child element?

`
<form #frm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(frm)">
    ... <add-user-component..></add-user-component..>
</form>
`

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You need the `ngControl` attribute on the inputs you want to check.

```
<form #frm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(frm)">
   <input [(ngModel)]="user.name" #name="ngForm" ngControl="name"  type="text">
   <a (click)="showFrm()">Show Frm</a>
</form>
```

and in the component you can access the "frm" variable with

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from 'angular2/core';
...
@ViewChild('frm') public userFrm: NgForm;
...
public showFrm(): void{
    console.log(this.userFrm);
}
```

You can't access the `frm` in the constructor, it's not there at this moment, but in the ngAfterViewInit you can access it.

since Angular 8 or so they have updated the parameters for ViewChild. Currently I need to use this syntax:

```
@ViewChild('frm', { static: true })userFrm: NgForm;
```

Comment: @squadwuschel I've tried to access the form controls in component in order to call setErrors() on each one. So, when I logged with console.log(this.frm.controls) I see the key value pairs in browser console, but when I try to iterate over this.frm.controls with for-in loop or try to get keys as array with Object.keys(this.frm.controls) it returns empty array. Have you experienced such problem? Any hint or advise would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the `#name="ngForm"` valid on the `input` element?

Comment: There's a small typo in your example - it should be `console.log(this.userFrm)` - not `console.log(this.fmr)`

Answer (score -1):

```html
<h1>Login</h1>
<hr />
<div class="col-md-4">
  <form autocomplete="off" #loginForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="login(loginForm.value)">
    <div class="form-group">
      <em *ngIf="loginForm.controls.userName?.invalid">required</em>
      <label for="userName">User Name:</label>
      <input
        id="userName"
        (ngModel)="(userName)"
        name="userName"
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="User Name..."
      />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <em *ngIf="loginForm.controls.password?.invalid">required</em>
      <label for="password">Password:</label>
      <input
        id="password"
        (ngModel)="(password)"
        name="password"
        type="password"
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="Password..."
      />
    </div>

    <button type="submit" [disabled="loginForm.invalid" ]class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'login',
  templateUrl: './app/login/login.component.html'
})
export class LoginComponent {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  login(formValues) {
    this.authService.loginUser(formValues.userName, formValues.password);
  }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.