# When using template driven forms in Angular 2, how to access the form in the component?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a simple template driven form like so:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Hero Form</h1>

    <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #heroForm="ngForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" [(ngModel)]="model.name" name="name" #name="ngModel">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="alterEgo">Alter Ego</label>
        <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="alterEgo" [(ngModel)]="model.alterEgo" name="alterEgo">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="power">Hero Power</label>
        <select class="form-control"  id="power" [(ngModel)]="model.power" name="power">
          <option *ngFor="let pow of powers" [value]="pow">{{pow}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!heroForm.form.valid">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from './hero';

@Component({
    selector: 'at-hero',
    templateUrl: './hero.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./hero.component.scss']
})

export class HeroComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() {
        //
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        //
    }

    powers = ['Really Smart', 'Super Flexible', 'Super Hot', 'Weather Changer'];

    model = new Hero(18, 'Dr IQ', this.powers[0], 'Chuck Overstreet');

    submitted = false;

    onSubmit() { this.submitted = true; }

    newHero() {
      this.model = new Hero(42, '', '');
    }
}
```

How can I:

1. Reset the whole form from the component (not from the markup)?
2. Reset a single form field (e.g. the name field) also from the component and not the markup?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 Template Driven Form access ngForm in component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37093432/angular-2-template-driven-form-access-ngform-in-component)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the `form` by using `ViewChild`

**Markup**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #heroForm="ngForm">
...
</form>
```

**Component**

```
@ViewChild('heroForm') public heroForm: NgForm;
```

I suggest you also to look at [**Reactive Forms**](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) too. I think this will be more handy if you want to work with `form` in the typescript, not in the markup